# Asterisk does not start up after Trixbox reboots

Tags: asterisk, trixbox

I have been struggling with this for a while and cant seem to find the solution. I am running Trixbox v2.8.0.4 Asterisk 1.6

Whenever my box loses power or when you reboot etc asterisk does not start - Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk.ctl exist?)

Which means I need to login and do an amportal start/ amportal restart. After this asterisk works 100% again.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

system v5 init.d script run one-by-one.

In case of trixbox that mean if sendmail NOT started, you not get started asterisk.

Sendmail will not start if you have incorrect domain name. If you have no dns, use something like trixbox.local

Answer (score 0):

The problem for one of my customers in this situation was SELinux.  Try:

```
# restorecon -R /etc/asterisk 
# restorecon -R /var/lib/asterisk 
# restorecon -R /var/run/asterisk.ctl 
# restorecon -R /var/spool/asterisk
```

This fixed the issue for them.